# How to cover exposed OSB flooring

Tags: deck, outdoor, decking, play-structures

I built a playhouse for my daughters a few years ago and it has a porch that is just part of the flooring (OSB housing floor) - I had painted the floor and that seemed ok for a while but now it's clearly pealing up and not looking too great. I would like to put some sort of decking to cover and protect it, but I'm unsure how to best protect the OSB from moisture.

My thoughts are

1. Cover in some sort of plastic or tar paper, then just put decking over the top and ensure they fit together
2. Cover it with a ton of liquid nails/ silicone and stick the decking over the top
3. Other ideas??

Comment: OSB and moisture should not get together.  Any chance of of removing it?  If walls are over it, can cut it out to the walls and replace with external plywood or decking.

Comment: Is the problem moisture from above (rain) or below (soil)?

Comment: It is fairly thick and moisture resistant OSB sub-flooring, and it's fine everywhere except where it's directly exposed to rain and sprinklers outside. It would probably be fine if I just kept up the paint on it - but I don't like the look of it - and I know if I moint something directly to the surface it will trap moisture